# Python: get function to extract strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to extract all of the codes of each city from this site in order to create a Python dictionary of the form:

```
('city' : 'institution code')
```

Starting from a string like:

```
<li onclick="fillEnte('ABANO TERME','2050540010');">ABANO TERME (PD)</li>
```

Where `Abano Terme` is the name of the city and `2050540010` is the institution code.

I know I should use a `GET` and than a regular expression, but I don't know how. Or should I use urllib2?

p.s. I'm an autodidact beginner, be patient.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried so far, and maybe we can help you from there?

Comment: Use `python-requests` for the HTTP requests part and something like `BeautifoulSoup` for the parsing. First solve the first problem - getting the content from the target website -, and once it's ok write this to a local file so you can work on the second part - extracting relevant data - without DOSing the website.

Comment: Oh and what does it have to do with PHP actually ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install and use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) and [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to do this as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

url = "http://finanzalocale.interno.it/apps/floc.php/ajax/searchComune"
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; U; CPU OS 3_2_1 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/7B405'})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

city_codes = {}

for li in soup.find_all('li'):
    city, code = re.search(r"'(.*?)','(.*?)'", li['onclick']).groups()
    city_codes[city] = code

print city_codes['ABANO TERME']
```

Which would give you:

```
2050540010
```

You can usually install these using:

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

The script first grabs the HTML using the requests library and passes it to BeautifulSoup to parse the HTML. Note, this website requires a suitable `User-Agent` to be specified, otherwise it will not return the data.

Next the script uses the `find_all()` function to get all of the `<li>` entries in the HTML. Each of these contains an `onclick=` attribute which is extracted. A regular expression is then used to extract both the `city` and the `code` parts out of the text. These are then used to build your `code_codes` dictionary.